# NumPy masked array not considering fill_value when comparing to scalar

Tags: python, numpy

I have a masked numpy array like the following:

```
mar = np.ma.array([0, 0, 100, 100], mask=[False, True, True, False], fill_value=-1)
```

So the two values in the middle are masked, calling `mar.filled()` would return `[0, -1, -1, 100]`.

I want to compare this array to a scalar `0`, i.e.:

```
mar == 0
```

which returns

```
masked_array(data = [True -- -- False],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = True)
```

Note that the `fill_value` is now `True` which is the default fill value for bool arrays but does not make sense for me in this case (I would have expected that it is set to `-1 == 0` which is `False`).

To illustrate my problem more clearly: `(mar == 0).filled()` and `mar.filled() == 0` do not return the same result.

Is this intended behaviour or is it a bug? In any case, is there a workaround to achieve my desired behaviour? I know that I can just convert to a normal array before comparison using `.filled()` but I would like to avoid that if possible, since the code should not care whether it is a masked array or a normal one.

Answer (score 3):

`mar == 0` uses `mar.__eq__(0)`

docs for that method say:

> When either of the elements is masked, the result is masked as well,
>           but the underlying boolean data are still set, with self and other
>           considered equal if both are masked, and unequal otherwise.

That method in turn uses `mar._comparison`

This first performs the comparison on the `.data` attributes

```
In [16]: mar.data
Out[16]: array([  0,   0, 100, 100])
In [17]: mar.data == 0
Out[17]: array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

But then it compares the masks and adjusts values.  0 is not masked, so its 'mask' is `False`.  Since the mask for the masked elements of `mar` is True, the masks don't match, and the comparison `.data` is set to False.

```
In [19]: np.ma.getmask(0)
Out[19]: False
In [20]: mar.mask
Out[20]: array([False,  True,  True, False])
In [21]: (mar==0).data
Out[21]: array([ True, False, False, False])
```

I get a different `fill_value` in the comparison.  That could be a change in v 1.14.0.

```
In [24]: mar==0
Out[24]: 
masked_array(data=[True, --, --, False],
             mask=[False,  True,  True, False],
       fill_value=-1)
In [27]: (mar==0).filled()
Out[27]: array([True, -1, -1, False], dtype=object)
```

This is confusing.  Comparisons (and in general most functions) on masked arrays have to deal with the `.data`, the mask, and the fill.  Numpy code that isn't `ma` aware usually works the `.data` and ignores the masking.  `ma` methods may work with the `filled()` values, or the `compressed`.  This `comparison` method attempts to take all 3 attributes into account.

---

Testing the equality with a masked 0 array (same mask and fillvalue):

```
In [34]: mar0 = np.ma.array([0, 0, 0, 0], mask=[False, True, True, False], fill_
    ...: value=-1)
In [35]: mar0
Out[35]: 
masked_array(data=[0, --, --, 0],
             mask=[False,  True,  True, False],
       fill_value=-1)
In [36]: mar == mar0
Out[36]: 
masked_array(data=[True, --, --, False],
             mask=[False,  True,  True, False],
       fill_value=-1)
In [37]: _.data
Out[37]: array([ True,  True,  True, False])
```

---

`mar == 0` is the same as `mar == np.ma.array([0, 0, 0, 0], mask=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `(mar == 0)` does not yield the desired output. But you can consider

```
np.equal(mar, 0)
```

which retain the original fill value.

Comment: This returns `[True, -1, -1, False]` which is also not what I want. My desired output is `[True, False, False, False]` (like when doing `mar.filled() == 0`).